# What's {} in void({})?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```cpp
auto f() { return void({}); }
int main() { f(); }
```

What's exactly the `{}` in `void({})`?
How is it interpreted?

<sub>Just out of curiosity, of course. Let's go a bit further anyway.</sub>

Note that both GCC 6.1 and clang 3.8 compile it with no errors ([`-std=c++14`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1)).
The latter doesn't complain, the former shows a warning:

> warning: list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized

Using [`-pedantic-errors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-errors-1) instead, GCC ends with an error while clang compiles it.

Is this discrepancy an error of one of the two compilers?
I mean, is it valid code that should be accepted or not?

Comment: In some languages, it denotes an empty table or list.  However, in type based languages, it should have a type specifier.  It does not have anything to do with being an initializer, so imo, it seems like some sort of empty block scope.

Comment: Sounds like a clang bug. This goes to [\[expr.type.conv\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2)'s "Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized ([dcl.init]) with the initializer.", which make no sense for `void`.

Comment: it looks as lambda expressions: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Lamda expresssions should be `[](){}` not `({})`

Comment: @T.C.: Wouldn't that prohibit the usual `(void) unused` expressions?

Comment: @GManNickG No. `(void) unused` goes via [\[expr.cast\]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cast#4.2) to [\[expr.static.cast\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#6). `void(unused)` goes to [expr.cast] via the first sentence of [expr.type.conv]/2 ("If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression.") The problem is that `({})` is not a "parenthesized single expression", because `{}` is not an expression.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, I get what you're saying now, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Conversions to `void` type as well as the possibility to returning a `void` value have been present in the C++ language since the very beginning. The only part that raises questions is the role of `{}` in this context.

A quick experiment with clang

```
int a({});
```

generates an error message saying

> error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'void'

which indicates that [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) interprets `{}` as a `void` value. This appears to be a non-standard behavior. I don't see any place in language specification that would say that `{}` should produce a `void` value in this context.

But since this happens to be the case in clang, there isn't anything unusual in `void({})` compiling in clang. Any value in C++ can be converted to `void` type, meaning that as long as the compiler accepts `{}` in this context, the rest just follows naturally.

In GCC, it is actually an error in `-pedantic-errors` mode:

> error: list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized

So formally it is an "error", not a "warning" in GCC.

---

The combination of opening `({` and closing `})` makes these compilers to interpret it as a GNU C language extension known as [Statement Expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) (which is incidentally supported by clang as well). This is, for example, what makes the following code compile

```
int a = ({ 3; });
```

Under that extension, the expression `({})` is seen as a statement expression of `void` type. However, this conflicts with the uniform initialization syntax in C++.

Comment: Clang trunk now produces a GCC-like error message for this case (since [this November](https://reviews.llvm.org/D25816)).

Comment: ... and [it happily also diagnoses OP's code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fyypiO2iebe2xE2B).

Comment: @T.C. And it's my fault not to have tried it against the trunk, of course. Thank you.

Comment: `({`..`})` will only be interpreted as a statement expression if in a context where an expression is legal.  Immediately after `void` (or other typename) is not such a context (a declarator is expected), so it seems unlikely that is relevant here.